# Can't figure out nest error after adding MongooseModule to AuthModule

Tags: nestjs

auth.module.ts

```
import { Module, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { User, UserSchema } from '../user/schemas/user.schema';

@Module({
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, UserService, JwtService, JwtStrategy],
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1800s' },
    }),
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
  ],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { Module, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { AuthModule } from '../auth/auth.module';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, AuthService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

error message

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?). Please make sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.
```

I'm importing Jwt from nest. Once Mongoose is added to auth.module I get endless errors when I try and update anything. I had a hard coded array to test out routes before and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-add provides to the `providers` array if they are provided from another module. Doing this will make Nest instantiate a new instance of the provider (breaking the singleton scoping), and will require you to have all of the configuration necessary for the provider (in this case, the `JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS`